# Error de CDN al invocar la clase

Tags: javascript, php, html

Recientemente estoy incursando en convertir una tabla a PDF y estoy usando jsPDF pero a la hora de invocar la clase `jsPDF()` pero a la hora de invocarlo me salta el siguiente error en la consola
[image: Error en consola]

he consultado en varias partes y no creo que sea que escribi mal al invocar la clase ya que en la documentación invocan asi creo que debe ser algo del CDN pero ya he cambiado los links por anteriores versiones u otras alternativas

```
<!-- CDN JSPDF -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

    function generarPDF(){
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text('HELLO WORLD',10,10);
        doc.fronHTML($('#tabla').get(0),15,15);
        doc.save('reporte.pdf')
    }
```

De igual forma simplemente quiero sacar un PDF de una del contenido de una tabla que se muestra en pantalla ya que se filtran los resultados con AJAX, estoy usando JS, PHP, Jquery asi que estoy abierto a otras librerias para realizar esta función o alguna solución al error

Comment: declaralo así: `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;`

Answer (score 1):

En las versiones recientes de la librería, debes cargar la variable global de este modo ([ver aquí para más detalles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510108/5587982)):

```
window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
```

Por otra parte, el método `fromHTML` ya no existe, debes cambiarlo por `html`.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
<!-- CDN JSPDF -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;

function generarPDF(){
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text('HELLO WORLD',10,10);
    doc.html($('#tabla').get(0),15,15);
    doc.save('reporte.pdf')
}
```